# Custom Java Compiler (Extension)

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I am attempting to add a feature to Java. You can find a description of it [here](http://pastebin.com/9hxpZv5b). I was wondering if there is a way to write a custom Java compiler (or an extension for the compiler). The code would still compile into standard Java code, so I wouldn't need a custom JVM (or JRE, whichever it is). If anyone knows of how to do this, let me know. If you know it's not possible, could you link me to proof (maybe a statement from Oracle)? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/

Comment: @univerio Scala would allow me to do this? Can you provide a link to a tutorial or sample class or anything at all?

Comment: http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/

Comment: Sorry, it was a tongue-in-cheek observation that it's much easier to use a mature language that somebody else has already written with the features you want than to fork javac.

Comment: @univerio My idea is not implemented in any language that currently exists.

Comment: If you are using a custom syntax, then annotation processing is not suitable.  Now I am curious, what is your improvement to generics?

Comment: A comment regarding the deleted answer about annotation processor: Depending on what you want to archive this a valid (maybe even the best) option. In Java 8 there are type annotations that you can add even to generics and wildcard types. You can't have new syntax but it's a powerful tool that doesn't require you to build a compiler.

Comment: @kapep See the link I just added to the question. My idea involved new syntax that would be illegal with the current compiler.

Comment: Writing a compiler is very involved, especially a complex language like Java; if you don't already have experience in the area (compilers and PL) you should start with something simpler. However, it looks like that your idea is already implemented in scala. Seriously, take a look.

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scala/Structural_Typing) is an introduction to the scala's structural typing, which I believe is exactly the same as your idea.

Comment: @univerio Awesome! That's exactly what I meant. What should I do with this question? Should I remove that link and leave it as a general question, should I reword it and accept what you just posted as an answer, or should I close the question?

Comment: @nrubin29 Based on my analysis of your idea, I do not think annotation processing would be appropriate.  Clojure handles this out of the box.

Comment: @nrubin29 You should reword your question since it seems like what you really wanted was either an existing language or help on implementing it yourself. I'll add a slightly more detailed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala targets the JVM and its [Structural Typing](http://java.dzone.com/articles/duck-typing-scala-structural) does what you want. Example:

```
def generateNickname(name: {def getName(): String; def setName(name: String): Unit}): String {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Compiler for Java (ECJ) is open source, so it's freely modifiable.  See the [JDT Core documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/).  However, @univerio's suggestion to look at Scala before taking this on is a good idea.  Scala fixes many of the shortcomings of Java but still compiles to JVM code, so existing Java libraries work seamlessly.